# how to run a function with package name and function name in golang?

Tags: go

I want to run a function without `import`, if i have function name and package name.

I tried use `loader`,`ssa` ... lib, but only get package name and function name. same the [example](https://play.golang.org/p/YHj2WuSiEK). I want to get output when run function with package name and function name

Have any solution?

Comment: Your import paths don't appear to be valid.  At least the third_party folder does not exist on the github repository.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? You want to import a package without using import? Could you make a smaller example, where it is clear what you want to do.

Comment: @apxp: yes, i want to import a package and run funcs of this package without `import`

Comment: @dieuhd But Go is a compiled language. If you use a function this function should be compiled. To do so you need to import that package or at least copy just the function inside your package.

Comment: Vendoring and dependencies are really a very big thing inside the Go community. Maybe you are interested in vendoring: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Bz5-UB7g2uPBdOx-rw5t9MxJwkfpx90cqG9AFL0JAYo/edit#!